# lookup to EJBHome from Outside the container via Standalone applicatiion failed

Tags: ejb, websphere, websphere-8

I have an EJB application which is Deployed in `WebSphere 8`

I am trying to connect it from Standalone java program following way

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
    props.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop//localhost:2809");
    Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    Object o = ctx.lookup("MyAppHome");
```

}

But this is leading to below exception

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "MyAppHome" not found in context 
"serverlocal:CELLROOT/SERVERROOT".
at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1228)
```

Further looking into it I found following supporting link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=ac01caaf-d2aa-4f3f-93b3-6f3d4dec3e6b

Here the answerer suggested using fully qualified bean name

```
java:global/ProjectName/ModuleName/BeanName!FullyQualif‌​iedNameOfRemoteInterface or BeanName#FullyQualif‌​iedNameOfRemoteInterface.
```

If it's a correct fix. Where can I find the Project name, Module Name and Bean Name? I do have `xmi` files in the project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to determine the JNDI name for an EJB in WebSphere is to look for the binding information in the server logs.  The JNDI names associated with each EJB interface are logged using the message ID `CNTR0167I`.  Fore example:

```
CNTR0167I: The server is binding the com.example.DatabaseBean interface of the DatabaseBean enterprise bean in the TestProject.war module of the TestProject application. The binding location is: java:global/TestProject/DatabaseBean!com.example.DatabaseBean
```

Notice in this example that there does not appear to be both a `project name` (i.e. application name) and `module name`, because this test project was a standalone `WAR` module with an EJB packaged in it. Project/Application name is only used for `EAR` files.

Also note that a `CNTR0167I` is logged for JNDI names in both the `java:global` and `SERVERROOT` name contexts.  So, in the error scenario above, it could be that the EJB was bound to `ejb/MyAppHome` and not just `MyAppHome`, so you can also determine the correct `SERVERROOT` JNDI name from the `CNTR0167I` messages as well.  Either JNDI name may be used to lookup an EJB.

Comment: Thanks. I tried lookup by `ejb/MyAppHome` I am getting the same error again. For `CNTR0167I` which logs should I check? There are so many logs in WebSphere for eg SystemOut.log, SystemErr.log, introspect.log, etc. Also, I want to clarify that the Standalone project is a simple java program it's not WAR module.

Comment: Sorry, `ejb/MyAppHome` was just an example/guess; often people define their EJB JNDI names in the `ejb` context, but that is not required.  The actual name to use would be found in the `CNTR0167I` message, which would be in the SystemOut.log file of the server process where the EJB application is installed.

The `project name` I was referring to is that of the EJB application, not of the client.  The client project name does not effect the lookup name of the EJB.

Comment: Unfortunately, determining the JNDI lookup name for an EJB can be complicated because there are so many different ways that it may be defined.  This article describes them in detail:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7K4U_9.0.5/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/ae/cejb_bindingsejbfp.html

Whether the JNDI name is defaulted or defined in ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml/xmi, the `CNTR0167I` message will log the actual JNDI name(s) used when the application starts, so is generally the easiest and most reliable way to determine the correct JNDI name to use on lookup.